# yarn run v1.22.5 error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/runner/work/

Tags: github, yarnpkg, github-actions

This is the GitHub Actions ci/cd yml code.

```
name: React build
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout master
        uses: actions/checkout@master

  - name: Cache node modules
    uses: actions/cache@v1
    with:
      path: node_modules
      key: ${{ runner.OS }}-build-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.OS }}-build-
        ${{ runner.OS }}-
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: yarn install

  - name: Build 
    run: REACT_APP_URL=${BASE} REACT_APP_SRC_URL=${SRC} yarn build
    env : 
      BASE: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_URL }}
      SRC: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_SRC_URL }}
```

This is the build error message.

```
Run REACT_APP_BASE_URL=${BASE} REACT_APP_SRC_URL=${SRC} yarn build
    yarn run v1.22.5
    error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/runner/work/MyRepo/MyRepo"
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
    Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I am trying to do an automated distribution with GitHub Actions. I made a commit from the master branch, but I get a React build error.
How can I fix it?